# moving Ubuntu installation on a dual boot system to a new hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, gpt, mbr

I had an old Windows 7 pc in a cleanroom, on which I installed Ubuntu 20.04 last year. It boots in legacy Bios. But the hard drive was quite small and as I started requiring more libraries on the Ubuntu, it filled up, until I could not compile codes anymore. Unfortunately there was no option to move new computers to the cleanroom.

I therefore added a new hard drive to the pc. At the same time I had worked on the Ubuntu alot and did not want to have a clean installation. So I thought of cloning the existing Ubuntu on the new hard drive, keeping the windows on the first one, and moving the linux to second one. I followed this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition). The new hard drive is a GPT one, not a MBR one. I followed the first steps, and created linux partitions on the second drive /dev/sdb, and cloned the existing installation on /dev/sda to the second hard drive. Right now the partitions look like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HDS72102
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xacac4a9e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   4194303   4192256     2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         4194304 413276159 409081856 195,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       413278206 471500799  58222594  27,8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4       471500800 488376319  16875520     8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       413278208 442572799  29294592    14G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       442574848 458196991  15622144   7,5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       458199040 471500799  13301760   6,4G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 3,65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFRX-68W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C83A757F-A61B-4837-91BA-0FAC700B6DD0

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048  218796031 218793984 104,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  218796032  355510271 136714240  65,2G Linux swap
/dev/sdb3  355510272 1011861503 656351232   313G Linux filesystem
```

I changed the UUIDs for the second hard drive, and these are the IDS now

```
/dev/sda6: UUID="dd927015-e6ef-42ff-9425-a69f1e9ab305" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="acac4a9e-06"
/dev/sda5: UUID="bf14b622-0982-496e-86aa-c251b683f44a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="acac4a9e-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="C436D90736D8FAFE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="acac4a9e-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="OS" UUID="326482BC648281F9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="acac4a9e-02"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="HP_RECOVERY" UUID="38CCDE7ACCDE323C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="acac4a9e-04"
/dev/sda7: UUID="f4efeebf-90ee-43d2-9009-8f17cecdcc9e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="acac4a9e-07"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="f270a5b7-5522-45c5-b786-579e14a5ace6" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Root" PARTUUID="64854bfb-abdc-4239-b4dc-370bcb8e6b98"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="dd927015-e6ef-42ff-9425-a69f1e9ab305" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="SWAP" PARTUUID="21c902e4-27e3-4468-8a9c-eafc25a875e6"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="e8815fb4-f207-47bb-a3c3-ac1eaa964f27" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Home" PARTUUID="aaf46669-0390-4a51-8246-efc1447fe5dc"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
```

The problem happens in step 5, when I am supposed to edit grub and fstab. When I remove the Ubuntu live flash and reset the computer, in the boot menu I can see the Ubuntu on /dev/sdb1. I boot in to my old linux on /dev/sda5 to edit the grub.cfg. The entries for Ubuntu on two drives look like the following:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-bf14b622-0982-496e-86aa-c251b683f44a' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  bf14b622-0982-496e-86aa-c251b683f44a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bf14b622-0982-496e-86aa-c251b683f44a
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic root=UUID=bf14b622-0982-496e-86aa-c251b683f44a ro  quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
}


menuentry 'Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sdb1)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-f5ca21f3-97f4-4c3e-be0b-d5fd2834d566' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  f5ca21f3-97f4-4c3e-be0b-d5fd2834d566
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f5ca21f3-97f4-4c3e-be0b-d5fd2834d566
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic root=UUID=bf14b622-0982-496e-86aa-c251b683f44a ro quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
}
```

Now what I did after are the following:
1- The guide mentions changing the uuid to the new one and also partition and drive names. I tried changing the first entry to point to the hd1,gpt1 rather than hd0,msdos5. and set the uuid, changed the fstab with the new UUIDs and tried the command:

```
shell> sudo grub-install -d /media/<new partition uuid>/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda
```

note: I have grub 2.
The updated the partition options following the guide. And I reset the system after. The boot options were still the same, and no matter what I get booted in my old linux.

3- also, the fstab included an auto UUID: f5ca21f3-97f4-4c3e-be0b-d5fd2834d566, which is also used in the grub.cfg for the Ubuntu on sdb. When I tried changing the second menu entry instead, this time I receive an error that this specific partition is not found. and I have to go back to the menu and again choose my old linux to be able to boot. So this also failed.

1- Probably the first questions is if I can move a linux this way to a gpt drive, while the boot partition is on the first MBR disk (or should I change the second drive necessarily to MBR?)

2- Given that the grub automatically has menu entries for the Ubuntu on both drives, which one should I change now? I would at the end hope to remove the linux on sda5, if that makes any difference. One question is that should I change the xy also for --hint-bios --hint-efi --hint-baremetal options as well?

3- And well, what I am doing wrong in this process? Or what should I do to change the grub config file correctly or install it correctly so I have the windows on sda2 and Ubuntu on sdb1? Is there a better tutorial/guide or a different process altogether that I should follow here?

Comment: In broad strokes: It was BIOS but now you want UEFI so you may clone the partition as you did but then also install Grub for UEFI (in an EFI partition) and adjust the fstab accordingly. You need to boot a live session and mount partitions to do that. I think (not sure) so advanced mode in Boot Repair can be used to do that.

Comment: You cannot clone from MBR to gpt. You probably convert drive from gpt to MBR and then max of 2TB as that is all MBR can be. Your gpt will need a bios_grub if BIOS booting or ESP for UEFI. Better to install so no issues of UUIDs & booting. Then copy /home, maybe some settings from /etc, an export of installed apts to reinstall & any other data partitions. I use rsync to backup and rsync from backup to new install. If you have to spend more than an hour repairing better to install & restore form backup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Answer (score 1):

So given that none of the comments were helpful, I answer my own question incase someone in future ends up in the same situation.

it is fine to keep the second one as GPT. The editing of grub.cfg should only change the uuid of the root partition for the second linux. The only issue was that the grub-install command should necessarily include the --boot-directory option to set the boot directory of the second hard drive. Otherwise it installs on the first hard drive and you can not boot in to the second one. When I provided the boot directory as well, I could boot and update grub.